# ¿Cómo bajar diferentes archivos desde controlador Spring mvc?

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-mvc, controller

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que mi método del `controller` me retorne archivos creados dinámicamente, y enviarlos a la vista y que se descarguen de a uno. He visto ejemplos pero solo de `pdf`, y en mi caso un método retorna uno o varios, un `txt`, y dos `csv`. Espero me puedan dar una mano, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En una sola solicitud sólo se puede descargar un archivo. Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es que si hay más de un archivo, se comprimen todos en un zip y se envían al cliente.

Java dispone de clases para crear archivos zip sin problemas.

Comment: Hola Calabacin gracias por responder, la solución que encontré fue que cada archivo creado se guarde en el temporal de java, y luego en un array guardar los nombres de los files, luego desde la vista, con js, mostraba los links de los files creados y que el usuario los baje a mano, en este caso el requerimiento era que el usuario pueda elegir que archivos bajar.